# comparing a row and including the null

Tags: sql, ssms-2012

I have a column that has numbers like this

```
p123
p139
d291
c9384
p393
null
null
c148
```

I want to compare this column where it says it includes only the p and null values. My code is:

```
WHERE (COLUMN NOT LIKE 'C%' AND COLUMN NOT LIKE 'D%' OR COLUMN IS NULL)
```

WHEN I have the condition COLUMN NOT LIKE 'C%' AND COLUMN NOT LIKE D%  it comes back with out the null, but when I add the is null value, it comes back with one a c column even though there is a comparison to not include ones with c. I don't know how to get the order right or what parenthesis to use.

Comment: You say `includes only the p` but you do `NOT LIKE 'C%' AND COLUMN NOT LIKE D%`. What is correct? So what if there was another record `A123`, should it be included or not?

Comment: Yes. There could be a case like that and it would be included. We just know we don't want c and d but don't want to exclude null.

Comment: This should work (after you fix the 'D%'). Please show a test case failing at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a wildcard:

```
where [column] not like '[cd]%' or [column] is null
```

this would exclude any rows beginning with either`c`or`d`. In your example the three rows starting with`p`and the two rows with`null`would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 WHERE COLUMN LIKE 'P%' OR COLUMN IS NULL
```

Regarding your comment to my answer, if what you want is all values that doesn't match "D" or "C" in the first character, then the WHERE conditional is this:

```
WHERE (COLUMN NOT LIKE 'C%' AND COLUMN NOT LIKE 'D%') OR COLUMN IS NULL
```

Comment: What if there were other rows that had other beginning letters than p and you wanted them too? Why does it still include a c value if you say not like.

Comment: @epv I don't get what you're saying. I built that where clausule according with this: "it includes only the p and null values". You want to collect also values starting with letter "c"?